# Proving a complex function is analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

If we have some complex function $f(z)$ with a derivative $f'(z)$ which is defined at every point except say $z_0$ does this mean $f(z)$ is analytic everywhere except $z_0$?

I.e. if $f(z) = \frac{1}{z-2}$ is it analytic everywhere except at $z=2$?

Comment: Yes. f will be holomorphic on the open set $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{z_0\}$ and thus analytic.

Comment: We also say that it is meromorphic on the plane, because it is analytic everywhere and except for the single pole.

Comment: Analyticity may be pointwise, local or everywhere in $\mathbb C$.